# Transform a 0-10V into 0-5V and use op-amps as buffers?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider

I would like to transform a 0-10V into a 0-5V so I can read it with "5V MCU" (like the AVR/Arduinos).

In the most basic case I would just put 2 resistors and do a divider, but since I don't know how that would affect the signal source I figure that I could add a buffer with op-amps since it would be safer.

So I could add a voltage follower on both sides of the divider.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2NBg4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or I could do a amplifier with amplification with 0.5 and then a voltage follower as a buffer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmlYsA.png)</sup>

Is it overkill to add the op-amps? Is it a good idea to do this kind of things, or is there another way?

Comment: Option 1 is fine with a rail-to-rail I/O op amp. Option 2 will not work as drawn.

Comment: @MattYoung what did I miss with nr2

Comment: A non-inverting amplifier can't have a gain less than 1. What you have drawn will have a gain of \$1+\frac{R1}{R2}\$

Comment: "OP:s" is not a standard abbreviation for op-amps where I live.

Comment: @markrages changed to op-amps to clarify the language.

Comment: @Johan if possible, can you spend just a few minutes trying to characterize the signal you're going to measure so you can absolutely rule out a simple resistor ladder? If you know *nothing* about the signal, it's possible your op-amps and their input impedance (and/or your lead capacitance) will cause problems. A pair of 100k to 10 MΩ resistors could actually give you better performance (depending on what you're measuring).

Comment: @NickT The signal is a slow DC that is controlling a water valve that is fully open when it is given 10V and closed at 0V (and 50% open at 5V). So there is no speed issues here, but I know where little about how the electronics that is sending the signal and how they can be affected. That is why I'm thinking about using op amps as buffers.

Comment: @Johan if you can't figure out what's driving the signal, I'd probably measure the voltage of the line, then see what happens if you pull it down with a 100k resistor. If it doesn't change much, I'd just make a ladder out of two of them and call it good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first circuit is fine. You could even use 100k resistors instead of 10k to save power. Note that your first op amp will need to *output* 0-10V, which means you won't be able to run it off of a 0-10V supply. If you don't have a rail-to-rail op amp, I'd recommend at least a +13/-3 V supply.

As Matt said, your second circuit will not work. The gain of a non-inverting amplifier cannot be less than 1. You could use a pair of inverting amplifiers, with the first one having a gain of 0.5. That would help with your output range as well, but there would be a small load on your source.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a higher voltage supply (like 12V) available, I would suggest a voltage divider and buffer amplifier.

For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyAX0X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

U1 has to be a RRIO (rail to rail on both the input and the output) op-amp (and should be a CMOS type with very low input current to use such high value divider resistors).

This also avoids the problem of the op-amp outputs exceeding the supply voltage of the micro under certain conditions (open input, for example), which would otherwise have to be dealt with to do things properly.

Comment: If you're using a voltage divider on the input, how much do you gain by adding a buffer? The input impedance of the op-amp might be 10-100 nA instead of ~1 µA (contrived numbers, probably way off), but it just seems like a waste unless there are specific performance concerns.

Comment: @NickT Well, he mentioned loading as a specific concern, and most uC ADCs don't like to see more than 10K to 2.5K on the input. If you can use a straight divider it won't add offset or any extra drift- the only downside is it's harder to protect the uC against transients or continuous overvoltage with relatively low Z. The 1M input Z I suggested would allow a relatively heavy 20nA input bias current before the error would be 1 lsb (assuming a 10-bit ADC). It's also nice to have the input go to some known condition if it's left open.

Comment: @NickT oh, and it takes less of a capacitor to act as a smoothing or anti-aliasing filter. 10nF rather than 10uF, for example.

Comment: For an ATtiny85 (random example), the input impedance is 100 MΩ and typical leakage <50 nA. Given it's a 10-bit ADC, wouldn't it be fine up to ~100 kΩ, or you could still use the 1 MΩ ladder and have ~1% error? I'm mostly just insinuating that the OP should understand the problem rather than just "oh, buffers are nice and fix lots of things so I should use a buffer.".

Comment: Maybe I'm just not giving the benefit of the doubt, but I don't read "I don't know how that would affect the signal source" as being concerned about source impedance, but more "I don't know what I'm measuring".

Comment: @NickT Fair enough. Probably more detail than we need to go into. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your requirements.  Do you need to sample at a very high frequency?  If so, you will definitely need to add some buffers.  The first circuit you have would work, presuming the op amps can achieve the required output swing.  The first amp will need to be powered off of at least 0 to 10 volts, and the second amp could be powered from 0 to 10 or 0 to 5.

However, if you do not require a lot of bandwidth, using a simple resistive divider will work.  Using a high resistance will ensure that the source is not loaded.  However, you will get droop on the ADC input as the ADC sampling capacitor charges up, so it would be advisable to add a capacitor to ground at the ADC input to smooth this out.

It may be a good idea to look in to using a single buffer as well, either before or after the divider, depending on bandwidth requirements and power rail availability.

Either way, the 2nd circuit is not going to do what you want it to as the gain of the first amp will be greater than 1.

Comment: good point with a capacitor to help/smooth the ADC, maybe a 10nF?